# Feathered edges on image with Pillow

Tags: image, python-3.6, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to figure out how to feather the edges of an image using Pillow with Python.

I need something like this cute cat (ignore the visible edges):

[image]

I tried `im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)` but is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at this example:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

RADIUS = 10

# Open an image
im = Image.open(INPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME)

# Paste image on white background
diam = 2*RADIUS
back = Image.new('RGB', (im.size[0]+diam, im.size[1]+diam), (255,255,255))
back.paste(im, (RADIUS, RADIUS))

# Create blur mask
mask = Image.new('L', (im.size[0]+diam, im.size[1]+diam), 255)
blck = Image.new('L', (im.size[0]-diam, im.size[1]-diam), 0)
mask.paste(blck, (diam, diam)) 

# Blur image and paste blurred edge according to mask
blur = back.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(RADIUS/2))
back.paste(blur, mask=mask)
back.save(OUTPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME)
```

Original image (author - [Irene Mei](https://www.flickr.com/photos/emyanmei/6458953837/)):

[image: Kitty]

Pasted on white background:

[image: Kitty pasted on white background]

Blur region (paste mask):

[image: Blur region]

Result:

[image: Image of a kitty with feathered (blurred) edges]

Comment: Note: result can be improved by adding gradient to the paste mask.

Comment: Your code works perfectly. Would you be able to show how to apply a gradient to the mask (so that the start of the feathered edges is less noticeable)?

Comment: @Crickets, see the answer below.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I asked a related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63016750/how-can-i-feather-an-image-horizontally-using-python - could you take a look?  Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Providing modified solution with gradient paste mask (as requested by @Crickets).

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw
from PIL import ImageFilter

RADIUS = 10

# Open an image
im = Image.open(INPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME)

# Paste image on white background
diam = 2*RADIUS
back = Image.new('RGB', (im.size[0]+diam, im.size[1]+diam), (255,255,255))
back.paste(im, (RADIUS, RADIUS))

# Create paste mask
mask = Image.new('L', back.size, 0)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(mask)
x0, y0 = 0, 0
x1, y1 = back.size
for d in range(diam+RADIUS):
    x1, y1 = x1-1, y1-1
    alpha = 255 if d<RADIUS else int(255*(diam+RADIUS-d)/diam)
    draw.rectangle([x0, y0, x1, y1], outline=alpha)
    x0, y0 = x0+1, y0+1

# Blur image and paste blurred edge according to mask
blur = back.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(RADIUS/2))
back.paste(blur, mask=mask)
back.save(OUTPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME)
```

Paste mask:

[image: Blurred black rectangle]

Result:

[image: Feathered portrait of a cat]

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Comment: Is it possible to blur to transparency instead of white? Can we do it without increasing the image width and height? Similar to this http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/#feathering

Comment: @pablo, you can try to create transparent background instead of white.

Comment: @AndriyMakukha I can't tell a difference between the images.  Which parts are feathered?

Comment: @mLstudent33, look at the bottom part of the image. In the first image you can clearly see the boundary between blurred portion of the photo and original. In the second image, the boundary itself is blurred.