# How can I optimize this wand code? It is very long to execute

Tags: python, optimization, wand

I have a code that takes 45 seconds on my local machine (It's a good i7 configuration). I'm currently using wand but I'm open to other library if you have an other idea. The goal of this code is to blur the middle of a picture and gradiently unblur until the border:

```
from wand.image import Image, CHANNELS
from wand.api import library
from wand.display import display
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.color import Color

with Image(filename='paysage.jpg') as img:
    points = {'black': (0, img.height), 'white': (0, 0)}
    img.sparse_color('bilinear', points)
    img.function('polynomial', [3, -3, 1])
    img.negate()
    img.save(filename='filtre.jpg')

with Image(filename='paysage.jpg') as src:
    with Image(filename='filtre.jpg') as dst:
        src.composite(dst, operator='blur', arguments='20')
    src.save(filename='paysagefiltered.jpg')
    display(src)
```

Thank you for your help :)

[image: picture before filter]
[image: picture after filter]

Comment: Try pillow-simd or opencv or a combination of both https://python-pillow.org/pillow-perf/

Comment: Thanks, you think it is possible to do this with pillow-simd??

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50787948/feathered-edges-on-image-with-pillow

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what I want :( on your example a part of blured image is pasted on picture, I want a real gradient

Comment: Well, it was an example of how to apply a blur mask. You could easily come up with a solution such as: 1 - create a 10 separate pieces of blur masks of length = orig_im.length, height = orig_im.height / 20 with blur radius that gets higher  with each iteration. 2 - stack blur layers top down 3 - mirror the stack in y direction apply the blur mask to original im. This might not be the best way of doing it, but it'll work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another shot at problem, that directly applies blur with gradually changing radiuses, cropping sections from the image, combining all into one image and apply a one last blur to smooth all transitions. You can adjust values to your needs.

```py
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

RADIUS = 0
INPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME = "./w2UR2.jpg"
OUTPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME = "./output.jpg"

# Open source image 
im = Image.open(INPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME)

# adjustable blur radius 
diam = 2 * RADIUS

w, h = im.size
step = int(h / 20)
result = Image.new("RGB", (w, h))

stack = []
for i in range(20):
    blur = im.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(diam / 2))
    crop = blur.crop((0, step * i, w, step * (i + 1)))
    result.paste(crop, (0, i * step))
    diam += (i < 10) - (i > 10)


# smooth out the whole image

result = result.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(1))
result.save(OUTPUT_IMAGE_FILENAME)
```

Result: 
[image]

And the run time on a 9 years old i5 is:

```
➜  ~ time python a.py
python a.py  1.03s user 0.35s system 131% cpu 1.049 total
```